# Angular how to pass 2 datas to child component and use ngOnChanges and SimpleChanges

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm tryng to send two variables to a child component and get the real time value of each variable, this was working fine with just one variable ([Message]="Message"), now i need to pass another data but i'm getting a console error: "Cannot find 'previousValue' of undefined". This error is triggered when i update totalAmountCart variable (getting data from sessionStorage) How can i solve this? Maybe another life-cicle hook? Thanks in advance

Child component (receiver):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, SimpleChanges, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Input() Message: string;
@Input() totalAmountCart: number;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    const previousValue1 = changes.Message.previousValue;
    const currentValue1 = changes.Message.currentValue;
    if (previousValue1 !== currentValue1) {
      this.userDetails = this.Message; 
    }
    
    const previousValue2 = changes.totalAmountCart.previousValue;
    const currentValue2 = changes.totalAmountCart.currentValue;
    if (previousValue2 !== currentValue2) {
      this.totalAmount = this.totalAmountCart;
    }

}
```

Parent Component (sender):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-store',
  template: '<app-header [Message]="Message" [totalAmountCart]="totalAmount"></app-header>',

})
export class StoreComponent implements OnInit{

  ngOnInit(){
    getUserData(){
      this.Message = '{ id: 1234, userName: Nick }'
    }
  }
  
  getSessionStorage(){
    this.totalAmount = this.storageProducts.map(x => x.amount).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i set two if conditionals to evaluate changes it's working, anyway i'm sure that there's a better way to solve this

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    if(changes.Message){
      const previousValue1 = changes.Message.previousValue;
      const currentValue1 = changes.Message.currentValue;
      if (previousValue1 !== currentValue1) {
        this.userDetails = this.Message; 
      }
    }
    
    if(changes.totalAmountCart){
      const previousValue2 = changes.totalAmountCart.previousValue;
      const currentValue2 = changes.totalAmountCart.currentValue;
      if (previousValue2 !== currentValue2) {
        this.totalAmount = this.totalAmountCart;
      }
    }
     
  }
```